# Prevent coder order : forget to call a unique function of certain fields (without v-table/std::function)

Tags: c++, templates, callback, c++14, data-cleaning

`MyArray<Callback>` is a simple library that tracks whether an integer exists,
 and call `Callback::call` when it is requested to remove an element:-

```
template<class Callback> class MyArray {
    bool database[10];
    public: MyArray(){ for(int n=0;n<10;n++){database[n]=false;}}
    public: void add(int t){database[t]=true; }
    public: void cleanUp(int t){
        if(database[t]){
            Callback::call(t);  //#1
            database[t]=false;
        }
    };
};
```

User of the above library is supposed to define some custom `Callback::call` to be used in `#1`.
Here are examples :-

```
std::string testStr="";
class Callback1{
    public: static void call(int t){
        testStr+="call1 ";  //some unique operation - designed by User
    }  
};
class Callback2{
    public: static void call(int t){
         testStr+="call2 "; //some unique operation - designed by User

    }  
};
```

Next, user is supposed to create a custom database-hub (`DataHub`), e.g. :-

```
class DataHub{
    MyArray<Callback1> db1_;
    MyArray<Callback2> db2_;  //#2 Whenever I add a new field e.g. "db3_" ...
    public:  MyArray<Callback1>* db1(){return &db1_;}
    public:  MyArray<Callback2>* db2(){return &db2_;}
    public:  void cleanUp(int t){
        db1_.cleanUp(t);
        db2_.cleanUp(t);      //#3 .... I tend to forget to add "db3_.cleanUp(t)" here
    }
};
```

Here is the example of `DataHub`'s usage :-

```
DataHub hub;
hub.db1()->add(5);
hub.db2()->add(5);
hub.cleanUp(5); //=> testStr = "call1 call2"
```

### Question

How to prevent coder error to forget to clean up some field (`db1_`,`db2_`,...) at `#3` without :-

- **trick that has v-table penalty or similar**
  e.g. v-table / virtual function /  std::function / function-pointer
- **hack magic or similar** e.g. macro / X-macro

If there is an automatic way that I don't have to update code of `DataHub<>::cleanUp()` manually, it would be great.

Here is **[the full working runable demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69ac3f071626ff9e)**.
In real cases, `Callback1`, `Callback2`, `db1_` and `db2_` have more comprehensive and unique names, and `MyArray` contains more complex class (not int).

It might be premature optimization to avoid "virtual", but I want to know if it is possible.

From downvote, I guess that I don't research enough and this question is too easy.
Sorry, I still can't find the answer.

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but why not use destructors?

Comment: @Aluan Haddad I also considered about it, but I have too limited knowledge to make destructor invoke appropriate `Callback::call` statically.  Thank.

Comment: I'm finding the use case hard to understand. Why does the user need to define `static` methods according to some pattern so that they can be called through a template?

Comment: @Aluan Haddad   User want to a database that has a callback. (sound strange, but it provide great comfort some usages) Thus, I provide a callback-slot through a template argument.  There is an alternative named virtual-function callback, but it is more expensive.

Comment: Why not pass take some `std::function`s in the constructor. You could also use a template for the function type.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad Because `std::function` is more expensive.

Comment: Have you benchmarked it? Also, I suggested templates as an alternative `template <class F>void (F f) { f(); }`. If I am calling your API and it claims to be callback based but I cannot pass you a lambda or something, I will be an unhappy consumer.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad  Yes, I have benchmarked.  `std::function` seem to usable in most cases (90%). However, I have situation that callback is a very trivial function (get/set), and I want to avoid it in such case (because 2x slower).

Answer (score 1):

Make DataHub a library template, similar in implementation to std::tuple, that does the cleanup.

Something like:

```
namespace detail {
    void cleanUp(int i) {}

    template<typename First, typename ... Rest>
    void cleanUp(int i, MyArray<First> & first, MyArray<Rest>... & rest)
    {
        first.cleanUp(i);
        cleanUp(i, rest...);
    }
};

template<typename ... Callbacks>
class DataHub {
    std::tuple<MyArray<Callbacks...>> dbs;
public:
    template<std::size_t index>
    auto get() { return std::get<index>(dbs); }
    void cleanUp(int i) { std::apply(std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(i), dbs), detail::cleanUp); }
};
```

Comment: There are a lot compile error, and this seems to > C++14.   After various fix, I still can't make it compilable.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62bdb2f1d8d76cf7

Comment: Ah, I messed up on the arguments to tuple_cat, i needs to be wrapped in a tuple. edited